# updating a table by moving data from one row to another multiple times

Tags: sql

have an sql table and I need to take row 2 and move data in column 4 & 5 and move it to row 1. The values in column 4 & 5 are dynamic (ie not the same each time)

background on the table. every 8 rows are grouped together (by an action_id ascending) to another entity in another table (but the other table isnt needed for this task)
for example

```
action_id = 839283 col 4 = space col 5 = space
action_id = 839284 col 4 = SMS col 5 = L1
```

i need to move the SMS & L1 to the row above and blank out the row where action_id = 839284
this will repeat multiple times.
I was thinking of creating a select into a temp table to get the rows i need to change (using 2 other tables as links) but i caon't work out how to move data from the one row to the other dynamically

Comment: Edit your question and (1) provide sample data and desired results; (2) a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: I don't understand. After all it seems you simply want to update the record with the minimum action_id with the values of the record with the maximum action_id and set the columns in all other records to null. Is this what you are after?

Comment: And what is this about 8 rows are a group? Which range? 839280-839287? Or 839281-839288? Or 839282-839289? ... Somehow the whole task including the data model seems queer. Maybe you want to elaborate and get help on both.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- sql server
- action_id values are always one apart

3 stpes:

```
select action_id as To_Empty
into #EmptyMe
from MyTable
where col4 is not null

with CTE as
(
select action_id,
       col4, 
       col5, 
       lag(col4) over (order by action_id) as n_col4, 
       lag(col5) over (order by action_id) as n_col5
from MyTable
where col4 is not null
)
update CTE
set col4 = n_col4, col5 = n_col5 

update MyTable
set col4 = null, col5 = null
where exists (select 1 from #EmptyMe where action_id = To_Empty)
```